# Move every n rows of a matrix to a new column in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a data structure like the following

```
stat_names values

stat1       0.3
stat2       0.5

stat_x      ...


stat 16     0.8
```

and I would like to convert it to a similar structure, so that every 4 rows a new column is created and those 4 rows are moved to the new column.

```
  A     B     C     D
stat1 stat5 stat9  stat13
stat2 stat6 stat10 stat11`
 ...  ...   ...    ...
```

Where "A", "B", "C", "D" is a a-priori user-defined column names vector.

Although this is trivial to do by hand in Excel, I would like to do this in R with a script that can be iterated across multiple inputs.

Comment: You could do `df1 %>% group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(nrow(.), 4, nrow(.)))) %>% mutate(n = row_number()) %>% spread(stat_names, values) %>% ungroup %>% select(-grp)`

Comment: I would assume that you want the values instead of the 'stat1', 'stat2',

Comment: Thanks. But there is an issue with this command, as it generates a column for each stat, where in each column all but one value (the corresponding one) are NA.

Comment: I didn't have a reproducible example

Comment: You should create a reproducible example, including desired output. Otherwise, we can't test code to see if it works for your purposes. Some guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I cast the data frame as a matrix and then back to a data frame to produce the desired result.

```
# Dummy data frame
df <- data.frame(stat_names = paste("stat", 1:16, sep = " "),
                 values = runif(16))

# Cast as matrix with 4 rows and then as a data frame
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(df$stat_names, nrow = 4))

# Rename columns
names(df) <- LETTERS[1:ncol(df)]

#        A      B       C       D
# 1 stat 1 stat 5  stat 9 stat 13
# 2 stat 2 stat 6 stat 10 stat 14
# 3 stat 3 stat 7 stat 11 stat 15
# 4 stat 4 stat 8 stat 12 stat 16
```

---

If you actually want `values` in this format, change `df$stat_names` to `df$values`.

Comment: A similar idea: `data.frame(split(df$values, cut(1:nrow(df), 4, labels = LETTERS[1:4])))`